# Why my button pulls away?

Tags: android, xml, button

When I create buttons in linear layout with HORIZONTAL orientation the top margin appears on one of them(left). It appears when I set height with a number(1000). If I set it with WRAP_CONTENT this unexpected margin doesn't appear.

`LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                1000, 1.0f);`

I attach image of bug

[image]

My code is

```
final Button[] btnTemp = new Button[answers.length];
    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    gameL.addView(layout);
    for(int i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        btnTemp[i] = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        btnTemp[i].setText(answers[i]);
        btnTemp[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        btnTemp[i].setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.fab_margin));
        btnTemp[i].setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        btnParams.setMargins(0,0,0,0);
        btnTemp[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_shape_btn);
        btnTemp[i].setId(listLast);
        if(i != 2) {
            final int finalI = i;
            btnTemp[i].setLayoutParams(btnParams);
            layout.addView(btnTemp[i]);
        } else {
            Timer f = new Timer();
            final int finalI = i;
            f.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btnTemp[0].getWidth(),
                                    1000);
                            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
                            btnTemp[finalI].setLayoutParams(params);
                            gameL.addView(btnTemp[finalI]);
                        }
                    });
                } }, 1000);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`LayoutParams.WRAP_PARENT` always adjusts itself according to the `ParentView`, If you want to set the height manually, then try to get it from `dimens.xml` file like

```
context.getResources.getDimens(R.dimen.value);
```

Comment: So i must write 
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(btnTemp[0].getWidth(),              Math.round(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.height_button)));
But it doesnt work